# Getting NoMethodError, undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, null

I'm a beginner and am trying to show tag names associated to books (through taggings) in my book index view. The problem is that for some reason I get `undefined method "tags" for nil:NilClass` when I run:

```
  <% for book in @books %>
  <div id="book">
    <div class="bookHeader">
      <h5 class="bookTitle"><%= link_to book.title, book %></h5>
    <div class="bookTags">
      <ul class="tags">
        <li>
          <% for tag in @book.tags %>
          <%= link_to @tag.name %>
          <% end %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    ...
  <% end %>
```

In the index file I have:

```
  def index
    @books = Book.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @books }
    end
  end
```

In console, it shows that I do have associated tags:

```
>> @book = Book.find(12)
>> @book.tags.count
>> 3
```

Now I'm wondering if I need to construct a statement for if the books have tags or something like that. Anyone have any ideas? If I need to provide more code let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on your code is that you have `<% for tag in @book.tags %>`, which `@book` doesn't exist. What you need is `<% for tag in book.tags %>`.

Comment: Well spotted. He should also change `<%= link_to @tag.name %>` to `<%= link_to tag.name %>`.

Comment: Thanks Thiago and mischa. I tried this earlier I think and didn't see results. But that's because the book I had tags on was buried in the list and I hadn't called .reverse on the index. Whoops!